# Window media Player issue in Firefox, Chrome, Internet explorer

Tags: firefox, media, windows-media-player

I am facing a quiet funny issue with Windows media player, I am using default window media player installed on client local machine to view media in browser. I open it lightbox which is developed by me and it seems it have no issue with the that.

When I open any media in browser it shows white screen, if I switch a tab, resize the window, or inspect it etc. it starts playing the media (i.e. video/audio) otherwise it is keep on showing white screen...

Check this in `jsfiddle`

```
http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/cHMEy/
```

(Specially in Firefox)